# Finding and listing matching text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm no sheet wiz. What I'm looking for is a formula that can make this happen.

I have a list of prohibited terms in Column C to E.
Cell B1 has a 200-character paragraph that I need to audit.
What I'm looking for is for Cell A1 to list all the words found in that paragraph that matches any prohibited term in Column C to E.

Again, I'm no wiz. Tried looking online for solutions but I can't seem to find something close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this formula that filters depending in if the words are found:

```
=FILTER (FLATTEN (C:E),FLATTEN(C:E)<>"",REGEXMATCH(B1,"\b(?i)"&FLATTEN(C:E)&"\b"))
```

`\b` allows to find complete words, and `(?i)` to make it case insensitive

Comment: Duuude! Works like a charm 

Additonnal questions tho...

How do I make the matching words get listed only in cell A1?

And can this formula get data from a different sheet or another Google Sheet altogether?

Thanks a bunch! I owe you a beer 

Comment: Wrap in JOIN: `=JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(...` . Change `", "` with the separator you choose. And for using other sheets, yes you can. Use `'Sheet 2'!C:E` for example got another tab or `IMPORTRANGE("URL of other spreadsheet","Sheet1!C:E")` for another worksheet. Notice that for IMPORTRANGE you should give permissions, do first a simple query like `=IMPORTRANGE ("URL","A1")` authorise the connection and then apply it to your prior formula

Comment: This is awesome! It's working. One final thing tho ~ there were characters like "$, *, +, ?, ^, etc." on the list. These appear in Cell B2 even if they aren't present in the paragraph.

(Also, do you have any references on where can I learn these things for GSheets and Excel)

...you are a lifesaver dude 